# java applet socket connection issue

Tags: java, security, sockets, applet, connection

The code i have used for socket communication works in a program run in command prompt, but when the same code is used in applet embedded in a webpage there is a security issue. It does not connect...
Please help me out, need to finish this in 3 days....
Server:

```
    public void run()
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(5555); // create a server socket and bind it to port number.

        Socket s2 = s1.accept(); // make the server listen for a connection.

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s2.getInputStream());
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s2.getOutputStream());
        while(true)
        {
            char[] buf = new char[150];
            String line = in.readUTF(); // wait for the client to send a line of text.
            if(line.equals("send"))
            {
                for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                    buf[i]=0;
                if(Traffic1.s1wiut) buf[0]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1wist) buf[1]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1wirt) buf[2]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1silt) buf[3]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1siut) buf[4]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1sirt) buf[5]='1';
            }
            String line1 = new String(buf);
            out.println(line1); // send the data to the client.
            out.flush(); // flush the stream to ensure that the data reaches the other end.
        }
    }
```

Client side:

```
    public void run()
{

    while(true)
    {
        int serverPort = 5555; // port number on which the server is listening.

        try
        {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); // create an object that represents the above IP address.

            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress,serverPort); // create a socket with the server's IP address and server's port.

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while(true)
            {
                char[] buf = new char[150];
                String line = "send"; // request string to send to server.
                out.println(line); // send the above line to the server.
                out.flush(); // flush the stream to ensure that the data reaches the other end.
                line = in.readUTF(); // wait for the server to send a line of text.
                buf = line.toCharArray();
                if(buf[0]=='1')     s1wiut=true;    else    s1wiut=false;
                if(buf[1]=='1')     s1wist=true;    else    s1wist=false;
                if(buf[2]=='1')     s1wirt=true;    else    s1wirt=false;
                if(buf[3]=='1')     s1silt=true;    else    s1silt=false;
                if(buf[4]=='1')     s1siut=true;    else    s1siut=false;
                if(buf[5]=='1')     s1sirt=true;    else    s1sirt=false;

                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

What can be done to fix this issue??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Answer (score 2):

1. An unsigned applet can only connect to the host it was loaded from.
2. Your applet tries to connect to 'localhost'. So the server must be running on localhost too. Is it? How are you arranging that?
3. You are using `readUTF()` to read, but `println()` to write. That won't work. `println()` needs `readLine()`, and`readUTF()` needs `writeUTF()`.

Answer (score -1):

**can you post what kind of error you are getting?even it is security related issue also**

a small suggestion:

i think you need to change your server code as follows (because server is always listen to accept for client socket)

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(5555); // create a server socket and bind it to port number.

        while(true){

        Socket s2 = s1.accept(); // make the server listen for a connection.

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s2.getInputStream());
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s2.getOutputStream());
        while(true)
        {
            char[] buf = new char[150];
            String line = in.readUTF(); // wait for the client to send a line of text.
            if(line.equals("send"))
            {
                for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                    buf[i]=0;
                if(Traffic1.s1wiut) buf[0]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1wist) buf[1]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1wirt) buf[2]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1silt) buf[3]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1siut) buf[4]='1';
                if(Traffic1.s1sirt) buf[5]='1';
            }
            String line1 = new String(buf);
            out.println(line1); // send the data to the client.
            out.flush(); // flush the stream to ensure that the data reaches the other end.
          }
       } // end of while
    }
```

and  your **client** would be like as follows

```
public void run()
{

    int serverPort = 5555; // port number on which the server is listening.

    try
    {
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); // create an object that represents the above IP address.

        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress,serverPort); // create a socket with the server's IP address and server's port.

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        while(true)
        {
            char[] buf = new char[150];
            String line = "send"; // request string to send to server.
            out.println(line); // send the above line to the server.
            out.flush(); // flush the stream to ensure that the data reaches the other end.
            line = in.readUTF(); // wait for the server to send a line of text.
            buf = line.toCharArray();
            if(buf[0]=='1')     s1wiut=true;    else    s1wiut=false;
            if(buf[1]=='1')     s1wist=true;    else    s1wist=false;
            if(buf[2]=='1')     s1wirt=true;    else    s1wirt=false;
            if(buf[3]=='1')     s1silt=true;    else    s1silt=false;
            if(buf[4]=='1')     s1siut=true;    else    s1siut=false;
            if(buf[5]=='1')     s1sirt=true;    else    s1sirt=false;

            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
```

Comment: So what's the actual difference? And how does this solve a security exception?

Comment: i aleready written server has to wait for accepting the clients every time but in the above logic in server code  accept only onc client request thats it but in client code client request are going to server continously  have a breif look at once in server code of my post as well as client code.

Comment: So the difference is the while (true) around the accept() in the server? Is that all? And how does this solve a security exception again?